# MEXC.COM python algo - options: any = {price: "example1", quantity: "example1"} and placing orders

Tags: python

ERROR CODE:
line 65
spot.new_order(symbol= 'ETHUSDT', side= 'BUY', order_type= 'LIMIT_MAKER', options: any = {price: str(ask1), quantity: str(size)})
^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

I am trying to place orders on the mexc.com exchange and i am having trouble with the api lib if someone could finish the code where it buys eth then sells for btc then sells the btc for usdt that would help or any guidance or help thank you

```
import json
import datetime
import os
from mexc_sdk import Spot
spot = Spot(api_key="mx0apikeyXDkeyA", api_secret="10secret5c2b2apisecret06507b44a847bb")

profit=0
file1 = open("profit", "r")
profit = float(file1.read())
file1.close()

file1 = open("step", "r")
step = str(file1.read())
file1.close()
        
while True:
    file1 = open("COAX", "r")
    coax = int(file1.read())
    file1.close()
    response = spot.depth(symbol="ETHUSDT")
    #response = response.json()
    #print("ethusdt:")
    result3=response
    bid1=float(result3["asks"][0][0])
    #print("  "+str(bid1)+" size="+str(result3["asks"][0][1]))
    


    
    response = spot.depth(symbol="ETHBTC")
    #response = response.json()
    
    
    response1 = spot.depth(symbol="BTCUSDT")
    #response1 = response1.json()
    
    #print("ethbtc:")
    #print("  "+str(response["bids"][0][0])+" size="+str(response["bids"][0][1]))
    result2=response
    ask1=float(response1["asks"][0][0])
    ask2=(float(result2["bids"][0][0])*ask1)
    sizebtc=float(ask2)/ask1
    
    response = requests.get("https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=1")
    response = response.json()
    #print("btcusdt:")
    #print("  "+str(response["asks"][0][0])+" size="+response["asks"][0][1])
    result=response
    ask1=float(result["asks"][0][0])
    
    
    if((bid1-(ask1*sizebtc))>0):
        profit+=(bid1-(ask1*sizebtc))
        file1 = open("step", "r")
        step = str(file1.read())
        file1.close()
        st0=[]
        st1=[]
        st2=[]
        st3=[]
        
        
        size=1/ask1
        spot.new_order(symbol= 'ETHUSDT', side= 'BUY', order_type= 'LIMIT_MAKER', options: any={price: str(ask1), quantity: str(size)})                 
        if(step=="1"):
            st0=spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHUSDT')
            while(st0!=[]):
                st0=spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHUSDT')
                print(spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHUSDT'))
                file1 = open("step", "w")
                file1.write(str(1))
                file1.close()
        
        spot.new_order(symbol= 'ETHBTC', side= 'SELL', order_type= 'LIMIT_MAKER', options: any = {price: str(ask2),quantity: str(size)})
        if(step=="2"):
            st1=spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHBTC')   
            while(st1!=[]):
                st1=spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHBTC')
                print(spot.open_orders(symbol='ETHBTC'))
                file1 = open("step", "w")
                file1.write(str(2))
                file1.close()
        
        
        spot.new_order(symbol= 'BTCUSDT', side= 'SELL', order_type= 'LIMIT_MAKER', options: any = {price: str(ask1),quantity: str(sizebtc)})
        if(step=="3"):
            st2=spot.open_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT')
            while(st2!=[]):
                st2=spot.open_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT')
                print(spot.open_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT'))
                file1 = open("step", "w")
                file1.write(str(3))
                        
    print("+"+str(profit))
    #result = marketApi.ticker(symbol)
    bidprice=result['bids'][0][0]
    bidsize=result['bids'][0][1]
    askprice=result['asks'][0][0]
    asksize=result['asks'][0][1]
        
        
    z=0
    json_d={}
    bidpricev=[]
    bidsizev=[]
    askpricev=[]
    asksizev=[]
        
    bidpricev.append(str(bidprice))
    bidsizev.append(str(bidsize))
    

    askpricev.append(str(askprice))
    asksizev.append(str(asksize))
        
    while z < 1:
        #print('bid= '+x+'  size= '+bidsizev[z]+'ask= '+askpricev[z]+' size= '+asksizev[z])
        dictv={}
        dictv["bid"]=(bidpricev[z])
        dictv["bid_size"]=(bidsizev[z])
        dictv["ask"]=(askpricev[z])
        dictv["ask_size"]=(asksizev[z])
        if z == 0:
            dictv["bid_price"]=(bidpricev[0])
            dictv["ask_price"]=(askpricev[0])

        json_d[z]=dictv

        z+=1
    z=0
    js = json.dumps(json_d, indent=4)


    file1 = open("db/ledger-"+str(coax)+".json", "w+")

        
    file1.write(js)
        

    file1.close()
        #file1 = open("bid.db", "a+")
        #file1.write(bidpricev[0]+"\n")
        #file1.close()

        #file1 = open("ask.db", "a+")
        #file1.write(askpricev[0]+"\n")
        #file1.close()


    file1 = open("COAX", "w")
    file1.write(str(coax+1))
    file1.close()

    file1 = open("profit", "w")
    file1.write(str(profit))
    file1.close()

    print(str(coax))
        #os.system("sleep 1")
```

Comment: `options = any={price: str(ask1), quantity= str(size)}` this does not make sense

Comment: `options: any ={price: ask1, quantity: size}